# DLNA Server in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, dlna

How do I use the built-in DLNA server in Windows 8 to replace something like TVersity? I pose this question with multiple parts:

- How is it enabled?
- How do I add my folders?
- How do enable sorting, to
  make is ez to find videos with my TV?

**Update**

I have found that this is totally possible and supported in the release version of windows 8, however I found it way too limited (doesnt play mkv etc...) and have since purchased [TVersity](http://tversity.com/); it works very well.

Comment: First search result in a Google search... http://mywindows8.org/how-to-use-dlna-server-in-windows-8/

Comment: Ah nice one! but they don't cover sorting or indexing of any kind. I think I need to get up-to-speed on DLNA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Windows Media Player can act as a DLNA Server

Comment: I hear that it comes with a DLNA provider / server; or is that only for a certain version like "Pro"?

Comment: Am I using the wrong term? I mean to read videos from my PC with my DLNA enabled TV; if my term is incorrect, do you know the right one?

Comment: Aaaah OK you can use Windows Media Player for that.